# Difficulty understanding Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

I don't understand the lorentz transformation. Consider:
$ \Delta x=\gamma (\Delta x^{'}+v\Delta t^{'})\\
\Delta x^{'}=\gamma (\Delta x-v\Delta t) $

For simultaneous events:
$ \Delta x=\gamma (\Delta x^{'}) $ and $\Delta x^{'}=\gamma (\Delta x)$

Which is what I don't understand. I guess that the $\Delta x^{'}$ and the $\Delta x$ have a different meaning in each of the equations but I don't understand what this is. My current understanding is that if I am in frame A and B is moving away from me, if an observer in B measures the distance between two simultaneous events ($\Delta x^{'}$) then from that and knowing B's velocity I should be able to determine what I should measure($\Delta x$).

But then I get stuck because those variables cannot be the same in each of the equations because you get the contradiction that $\gamma = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x^{'}}$ and also is $\frac{\Delta x^{'}}{\Delta x}$

I would appreciate an answer that doesn't involve matrices (though I doubt this even needs them) because the lecturer derived the transformations without them.
Thanks

Comment: Events that are simultaneous in one frame are not (necessarily) simultaneous in another. So if $\Delta t$ is zero, $\Delta t'$ will not in general be. If you work through the math in a concrete example, you will see that this fixes the apparent paradox

Comment: You can't have $\Delta t = 0$ AND $\Delta t' = 0$ simultaneously. As mentioned by @JakobKS, in special relativity, simultaneity is itself a relativistic concept (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This form of the Lorentz transform is for two events in spacetime. $\Delta x$ is the spatial distance between those two events in the unprimed frame and $\Delta x'$ is the spatial distance between those same two events in the primed frame. Similarly for $\Delta t$ and $\Delta t'$.

Those variables have the same meaning in both equations. However, you are also missing two other important equations for the Lorentz transform. $$\Delta t = \gamma \left(\Delta t'+\frac{v\Delta x'}{c^2}\right)$$ $$\Delta t' = \gamma \left(\Delta t-\frac{v\Delta x}{c^2}\right)$$

> For simultaneous events:
> $ \Delta x=\gamma (\Delta x^{'}) $ and $\Delta x^{'}=\gamma (\Delta x)$

Here is where you go wrong. You have mistakenly obtained this equation by setting both $\Delta t=0$ and also $\Delta t'=0$. This is incorrect. From the equations that you were missing if $\Delta t'=0$ then $$\Delta t = \gamma \frac{v\Delta x'}{c^2}$$ which is not zero unless $v=0$ or $\Delta x'=0$. This is the relativity of simultaneity. Two events which are simultaneous in one frame ($\Delta t'=0$) are not simultaneous in another frame ($\Delta t\ne 0$). This concept is the most difficult one to grasp in relativity, and is the source of most of the relativistic "paradoxes".

Assuming neither of those special cases hold then you have $\Delta x=\gamma(\Delta x')$ and $\Delta x'=\gamma(\Delta x - v\Delta t)$. The contradiction you found does not arise.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I understand how your answer applies between events, but what if you are measuring the length of an object, how does it reduce to the length contraction formula? Is that it reduces only in one frame, but in the other the delta t is not 0?

Comment: @ED2468 in length contraction you are not looking for the distance between two events. Instead you are looking for the distance between two parallel worldlines. You use the form of the transforms without the $\Delta$ symbols in it

Comment: @ED2468. You know $\Delta x=L$ in the "moving" frame and want $\Delta x$ in the observer frame when $\Delta t=0$ for the observer. If the primed variables are for the "moving" frame, then you can use
$$\Delta x' = \gamma\left( \Delta x - v \Delta t \right)$$
to get
$$\Delta x = \gamma^{-1}\Delta x',$$
where I have used $\Delta t=0.$

Answer (score 2):

Let's first look at a more 'basic' form of the Lorentz transformation, with no reference of deltas.

\begin{align}
x'&=\gamma(x-\beta(ct))\\
ct'&=\gamma(ct-\beta x)
\end{align}

This says the following. Let's say I have an event in spacetime, labelled (ct, x) by an observer $S$. I now switch to a different observer $S'$, moving at a speed $v$ with respect to $S'$. This new observer will assign different coordinates to this event, namely $(ct', x')$. The way to get these new coordinates is by the Lorentz transform. Here is an animation of the Lorentz transform with $\beta$ linearly increasing in time, and the points chosen in a clever way such that they loop nicely. I think recreating this for yourself with a few points would be a nice exercise.

[image]

How do we get the formula with deltas? Let's say we have a point $p_1=(ct_1,x_1)$ and $p_2=(ct_2,x_2)$. The Lorentz transformation is linear, so it turns out the displacement vector $\Delta p=p_2-p_1$ also transforms the same way! Writing $\Delta p=(c\Delta t,\Delta x)$, we get exactly the same formula you quoted.

So what do these delta-quantities mean? They mean the displacement between two events in spacetime. Is $\Delta x$ the length of an object? It *can* be, but only if the displacement in time is zero. Similarly, $\Delta t$ is only the time between events if $\Delta x$ is zero.

Let's say for example we measure the length of a stick in the frame $S$. This gives the following displacement:
$$\Delta p=(0, L)$$
Note that the time displacement is zero. Now, in the frame $S'$ this becomes
$$\Delta p'=(-\beta\gamma L, \gamma L)$$
Can we say the length of the stick is $\gamma L$ in frame $S'$? No! We are measuring the length between different points in time and this doesn't make sense. We have to do some more work. After having done that work, you will get $L'=L/\gamma$.